# Office.context.ui.closeContainer() does not close task pane window

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to configure a 'Cancel' button that closes the task pane when clicked using [Office.context.ui.closeContainer()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.closecontainer).

I tried implementing this method several different ways. Firstly, via a jQuery click handler. Then by itself in a function declaration that is clicked via the HTML `onclick=""` attribute. Every time it throws an error:

> 'closeContainer is not a method of the object', 'closeContainer' is undefined.'

Even when I open up the debugger and peek into the `Office.context.ui` Object, that method is not listed there.

I am initializing Office at the top of my script so that is not the issue. The docs say that "This method closes the UI container where the JavaScript is executing." but that doesn't seem to be the case unless my implementation is wrong.

Comment: What host program (outlook, word, excel, etc) are you using this in?

Comment: I'm building an Excel Web Add-in, XML/HTML/CSS/JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closeContainer API currently only works for Outlook hosts; we will update our docs to make that clear; thanks for pointing that out. It is in our backlog to enable it for other hosts in the future but we don't have an ETA to share. As a workaround for dialogs you can use the messageParent method on the dialog and then close method on the dialog object to achieve a similar outcome as described in our [docs](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). There is however no way to programmatically close a taskpane in W/XL/PPT currently.

Comment: well ya'll have made a ton of useful videos, maybe its time to start chopping away at the backlogs :)

Comment: The messageParent works fine for closing the custom child dialog. However, in my case , I am using Azure AD authentication where I cannot place the javascript on the child window since it redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com . So i got hold of the referrer and redirected the user to another page and placed the javascript to close it. It works fine in OWA, however fails in Outlook on Windows.