# Outlook Add-in Desktop : Office.context.ui.close() not working on desktop version

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm building an outlook add-in for web and desktop users.
And I'm struggling to find the method that closes the add-in for the desktop version

In my Add-in, I inserted a button that invokes

```
Office.context && Office.context.ui && Office.context.ui.closeContainer();
```

onClick to close the add-in.
This works on the web version of the add-in but not on the desktop one,
Is there a problem with my code or is the desktop version not supporting this method ?

**Environment setup :**
Microsoft Outlook 2016 (16.0.5182.1000)
Exchange 2016 (build version 15.1.2375.7) on-premise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work for task panes on the desktop. Here is the description for the [closeContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview#office-office-ui-closecontainer-member(1)) method:

> Called from a task pane: The task pane will close. Any dialog opened by `displayDialogAsync` will also close. If the task pane supports pinning and was pinned by the user, it will be un-pinned.

But the minimum requirement set is 1.5 where Outlook 2016 is not supported.

Also you may find a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038469/office-context-ui-closecontainer-does-not-close-task-pane-window).

Comment: Note that closeContainer is in requirement sets Mailbox 1.5, which is not available in Outlook 2016 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview#:~:text=Outlook%20add-ins%20declare%20what%20API%20versions%20they%20require,API%20requirement%20set%20that%20supports%20the%20add-in%27s%20scenarios.

Comment: Gotcha! Removed the part with filing an issue.

Comment: Thank your for the answers, you saved me a lot of time :)